# writing unique functions with the same arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I want to write a state machine class that works like the following

```
from states import StateMachineExample

sm = StateMachineExample()

while True:
    a = input_source1()
    b = input_source2()
    c = input_source2()

    sm.tick(a,b,c)
```

The StateMachine class keeps track of the states and all the user has to do is to feed it with the new inputs each cycle using `tick()`. The class definition would be something like the following:

```
class StateMachineBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self,init_state):
        self._state = init_state

    def tick(self,*args):
        """
        Let the state machine process the next set of inputs.
        """
        # The next state is defined by what the current state's
        # function returns
        newstate = self._state(*args) or self._state
        self._state = newstate

class StateMachineExample(StateMachineBase):

    def __init__(self):
        super(StateMachineExample,self).__init__(self,self.StateA)

    def StateA(a,b,c):
        if condition_on(a,b,c):
            return self.StateB # Transition to StateB
        else:
            return self.StateA

    def StateB(a,b,c):
        if other_condition_on(a,b,c):
            return self.StateA
        else:
            return self.StateB
```

**Question**

Is there anyway to avoid having to explicitly state the `a,b,c` arguments for each function (state) definition in the StateMachineExample class? I.e. is it possible to define the arguments in one place and have that define the arguments for a whole set of functions? I realize this whole implementation may be really flawed so I'm certainly open to different approaches.

**Notes**

It's possible to do this with `*args` but then the arguments have to be referenced with respect to the args tuple. I want to be able to refer to the args by name within the functions, i.e. `a,b,c`.

The closest solution I found was to define the inputs as class member variables that can be updated on each call to `tick()`. I'm hoping there is something more elegant than this though.

Comment: Why are you defining the state machine via code instead of data?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Can you elaborate? The point of the class is to allow for abstracting the details of a state machine that is defined at interpretation time. If it helps, the state machine in my case recognizes and segments a hand in a video feed. So (roughly speaking) the input for each cycle is an image from a camera feed. The user can then check the class instance to see if the state machine is currently tracking the hand and retrieve relevant attributes like the bounding box of the hand.

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio mentioned, state machines are generally dependent on a variable which points to the next state to be executed. This  'next' state is generally called frequently, and changed only if necessary (if there is an event which causes a change of state). From there on, that new state is the one being called, till the next event appears.

So, if you have a series of events, and the switching is common (frequent - almost on each cycle), then a state machine does not make too much sense. You just implement a series of if statements.

Generally, in a state machine, you will have a variable which contains the reference to the next function to be called. When an event occurs this variable is changed to the next state.

Say you have a variable 'routine_to_go_to_work'. Normally this variable contains a reference to 'Walk_to_work'. But if you break a leg, you change the variable to point to 'Call_a_taxi'... Till you recuperate and repoint the variable to 'Walk_to_work'. But you always call to the 'routine_to_go_to_work', whichever actual function it's pointing at.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. I think what's unclear is that I have made the tick of the clock an 'event' in my case (hence the `tick()` function). On a lower level, the machine processes the input on each iteration and then uses that to decide if a higher level event has occurred (e.g. hand was detected in video). I think what you're suggesting is that I define the conditions for these events outside of the state machine and call the machine only when an event occurs. Is that right?

Comment: Did you these examples? (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-python-state/ there seem to be some issues with formatting). They are quite interesting... It's quite similar to what I wanted to suggest (i.e. call the functions from a pointer. In this example all functions are in a table)

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Just to summarize: the idea stated there is that the StateMachine takes some initial input from the user and from there the state functions handle passing data from one state to the other internally. As the example states, the data that is passed around will probably include a kind of file handler from which the state machine can request new input. This seems like the solution I was looking for. Thanks!